# Как сделать SSD диск Windows 10 загрузочным без потери данных?

Tags: windows, ssd

Старая система Windows 10 стоит на HDD. Диск разбит на С и D. C - загрузочный.
Поставил SSD с целью переноса всей системы на него, копировал зеркально c разделами. На SSD создалось также два диска E и F.(зеркальные копии С и D).  При отключении HDD, комп  с SSD не загружается, так как загрузочного сектора нет. Что посоветуете чтобы система Windows 10 запускалась с SSD?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Нужно сделать копию диска, если размеры не совпадают, то сделать пропорциональные разделы. Если  не загружается, копия сделана не правильно или не выбран загрузочный диск.

Comment: Производители SSD, как правило, имеют свои абсолютно бесплатные официальные утилиты для миграции. Скачайте утилиту и мигрируйте. У Crusial даже от Acronis утилита.имеется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте загрузочный сектор в ручную на SSD через утилиту bootrec.exe.
Инструкций в интернете по этому поводу достаточно, поэтому дублировать не вижу смысла.
Или у вас просто не выбран загрузочный диск. Слишком мало информации присутствует в описании заголовка.

К тому же существует множество сервисов для клонирования жесткого диска:

Acronis True Image,
AOMEI PARTITION ASSISTANT
и т.д.

Но лично я ни когда не пользовался ими. Всегда прогонял через утилиту, так как для меня это более привычней.

P.S. Возможно и обойтись исключительно утилитой bcdboot.exe. Проще намного будет.

Comment: Все получилось, создал клон с помощью Renee Becca (pro версию ключ поставил). Диск сделал системным. Потом отключил HDD, загрузку в биосе на SSD перевел, потом HDD как резервный подключил. Все летает, всем спасибо!